# Making an element disappear when at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website but I don't know much about javascript or jquery. I have a down arrow on my homepage showing that there is more information but I want it to go away when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page because it is then not needed because they can't scroll down anymore. I know I will need javascript or jquery to do this but I don't even know where to start with it. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var numPix = 200; // number of pixels before bottom of page that you want to start fading
  var op = (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop()) / numPix;
    if( op <= 0 ){
        $("#thing-to-hide").hide();
    } else {
        $("#thing-to-hide").show();
    }
    $("#thing-to-hide").css("opacity", op ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
document.onscroll = function() {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
            document.getElementById('arrow').style.display='none';
        }
    }
```

Where 'arrow' is the id of the image.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but do I just put that in a script tag in my html file?

Comment: Yep, you could do that.  Since my answer doesn't rely on jquery, you don't have to worry about referencing it or anything else.  Let me know if you're still having trouble.